# What differences exist for compiled WebViewPage-derived class generated from an ASP.Net MVC view vs. a partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I understand that in ASP.Net MVC, razor views are compiled into C# classes that are derived from the System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage class or its generic version.  For example, if I have a view named "Index" on a controller call "Home", the razor parser will build a C# class that looks something like this:

```
public class _Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage
{
    public  _Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml() 
    {  }

    public override void Execute() 
    {
        ...code that combines the razor C# code with the markup
    }
}
```

I am wondering about the C# class that is generated from razor partial views.  In particular:

1. Does the C# class that is generated from partial views also inherit from WebViewPage?
2. Are there any differences in the generated C# class between views and partial views?
3. Can you tell by inspecting a generated C# class if it was generated from a view or from a partial view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ASP.NET MVC and Razor there is no difference at all between the generated code of a "full" view and a "partial" view. In fact, no such concept even exists in MVC's Razor view engine (or in ASP.NET Web Pages with Razor, for that matter).

The only small difference (which does not exist in MVC) is that in ASP.NET Web Pages with Razor a file that begins with an underscore is not directly servable. For example, a file such as ~/_page.cshtml cannot be run directly by a web request, whereas a file such as ~/page.cshtml would be. But even that difference is not in the compiled code - it's in ASP.NET Web Pages' routing system that refuses to serve files that start with an underscore.